# Python + Facebook, getting info about a group easily

Tags: python, django, facebook

I have a need to display some basic info about a facebook group on a website i am building. All i am really looking to show is the total number of members, and maybe a list of the few most recent people who joined.

I would like to not have to login to FB to accomplish this, is there an API for groups that allows anonymous access? or do i have to go the screen scraping route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Python Facebook module on Google Code.